# how to post counter value from javascript to database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have a java script function i want to post value of counter to my data base... how to do...this is a function to create 2 texbox and 1 select box on click... but whn i am applying another input tag to get and post counter value another input text box is getting reated... i dont want this i just want to post total value to counter whn submitt buttion is clicked

```
<script>
 var counter=1;
    function generateRow() {
    var count="<font color='red'>"+counter+"</font>";
   var temp ="<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='stop"+counter+"' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='timing"+counter+"' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><select id='ampm"+counter+"' name='ampm"+counter+"'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>";

var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = temp + count;

var yourDiv = document.getElementById('div');
yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
counter++;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolute most basic way I can think of is:

Add an iframe somewhere in your page:

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Create a php file **counter.php**

```
<?php

$counter = (int) $_GET['counter'];

$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (counter) VALUES (' . $counter . ')');
// OR YOUR OWN QUERY TO DO THIS

?>
```

And add to your function the following javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'counter.php?counter=' + counter;
```

Obviously you can do it more complicated via ajax and read the json response etc but at its most basic level, this will suit you. Basically the trick is, you set the iframe source to the `counter.php` and pass the counter in a get parameter. When an iframe source is changed, it automatically loads, hence the server will then recieve the counter parameter and process it.

You can add `display:none` to the iframe to hide it visually.

Answer (score 0):

Given the tags on the question:

Make an HTTP request (possibly [using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)) to a PHP handled URL that reads the data (likely from [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)) and uses the [PDO API](http://php.net/pdo) to make an SQL query using that data.